# how can i cover bootstrap css style?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass

I used bootstrap-sass gem in my project. The bootstrap.css file have defined .btn style.
I wrote a CSS file and defined .btn style likes

>
 `.btn a{ width:90px; height:25px; line-height:25px;  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#3588D4), to(#3287D0));background-image:linear-gradient(#3588D4,#3287D0); display:block; float:left; border-radius:5px; margin-right:15px; padding:0 5px; margin-top:8px;}`

So i want to replace my .btn to bootstrap.css .btn , how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

For overriding a bootstrap class permanently, what i do is make a separate css file named bootstrap_override.css in assets and put all the bootstrap classes there that i want to override. If you aren't using require_tree in your application.css then you have to include that file separately.